# shift+space changes language in fedora (Gnome desktop)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, gnome, hotkeys

`Shift`+`space` is nowhere defined to change language but it does!
It's super annoying because `shift`+`space` normally should insert non-breaking space which is so frequently needed in Persian.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you working with an "off-the-shelf" implementation of Fedora and Gnome (you haven't customized anything or redefined those keys, etc.)?  The language is set in Fedora's system settings and just a single language is set anywhere, or what other languages are set and where?  Does Shift-Space change languages in every app or just a specific one?  What language does it change it to?

Comment: 1. Yes I do. I just remember I touched language settings maybe during the setup. 2. I added Persian in inputs. So it's En and fa now. 3. Yes it does so in every app. 4. The alternative language. If it's fa , it's changed to en and vice versa.

Comment: It looks like Linux provides for keyboard shortcuts to switch languages.  Shift-space may be a default setting, but you may be able to change that.  I spotted this article about Ubuntu: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/.  Fedora is probably similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Firsly, you need to check out what are using this combination:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep ‘\<Shift>space’
```

I got that it used by `ibus engine hangul`.

Secondly, you can stop it:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.engine.hangul switch-keys "[]"
```

or install `dnf install dconf-editor`to view and edit it with gui